# How to transpose the first rows into new columns in R?

Tags: r

I want to transpose the first two rows into two new columns, and remain the rest of data frame. How do I do it in R?

My original data

```
A <- c("2012","PL",3,2)
B <- c("2012","PL",6,1)
C <- c("2012","PL",7,4) 
DF <- data.frame(A,B,C)
```

My final data after transpose

```
V1 <- c("2012","2012")
V2 <- c("PL","PL")
A <- c(3,2)
B <- c(6,1)
C <- c(7,4) 
DF <- data.frame(V1,V2,A,B,C)
```

Where V1 and V2 are the names for new columns and they are created automatically.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Are the values in those first two rows always constant?

Comment: (1) So you know, your vectors are no longer mixed `character` and `numeric`; the moment you combine classes in a `c(...)` vector, they are up-classes to the closest common class, which in this case is `character`. This means `A` is now `c("2012","PL","3","2")`. This is an R thing. If you need difference, use `list`. If you cannot change that process, look at the `t()` transpose function, and then convert your data afterwards with `as.numeric`.

Comment: (You might also revisit previous questions with answers and accept something.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an option with `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
   select(A) %>% 
   slice(1:2) %>% 
   t %>% 
   as.data.frame %>% 
   bind_cols(DF %>% 
             slice(-(1:2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R:

```r
cbind(t(DF[1:2, 1, drop=FALSE]), DF[-(1:2),])
# Warning in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
#   row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded
#      1  2 A B C
# 1 2012 PL 3 6 7
# 2 2012 PL 2 1 4
```

though I have some concerns about the apparent *key* property of `"2012"` and `"PL"`. That is, you start with three instances of each and end with two. Logically it makes sense, though really to me it looks as if you have a matrix of numbers associated with a *single* `"2012","PL"`, but perhaps that's not how the data is coming to you. (If you can change the format of the data before getting to this point such that you have a matrix and its associated keys, then it might make data munging more direct, declarative, and resistant to bugs.)

Comment: Could be probably even `data.frame(V1 = DF[1, 1],
           V2 = DF[2, 1],
           DF[-(1:2), ])`.